# Inner join removed from the SQL query

Tags: postgresql

I have a below SQL query to get the three records for notifying purpose.

```
SELECT orders.msg
FROM orders
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM orders
    WHERE type_id = 12
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0
) AS items
    ON orders.id = items.id;
```

When trying to make the query optimized, i made the changes as below.

```
SELECT orders.msg
FROM orders
WHERE type_id = 12
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0;
```

Is the modified query seems to be OK or did i miss anything here or any other way of doing is there??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplified version on the bottom looks logically identical, to me, to the one on top:

```sql
SELECT msg
FROM orders
WHERE type_id = 12
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Note that the above query could benefit from the following index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON orders (type_id, id, msg);
```

This index would completely cover the `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, and `SELECT` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:

```
SELECT orders.msg 
FROM orders 
WHERE orders.id 
IN ( 
    SELECT id 
    FROM orders 
    WHERE type_id = 12 
    ORDER BY id 
    DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0
   )
```